# Google Apps Script Regex returning nothing

Tags: html, regex, google-apps-script, tags

I am trying to strip HTML tags out of a string. It works on regex checkers, but not in this code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var textstfu = "<b> I love </b> pancakes <i> I love pancakes </i>";
  textstfu.replace(/(<(\D)>)([^<>])+(<\/(\D)>)/gi, "$3");
  Logger.log(textstfu);
}
```

What it returns is `<b> I love </b> pancakes <i> I love pancakes </i>`.
What's going on here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not assigning the replacement expression to a variable (.replace is a prototype function and does not assign back to the original property).

Try:

```
function myFunction() {
  var textstfu = "<b> I love </b> pancakes <i> I love pancakes </i>";
  textstfu = textstfu.replace(/(<(\D)>)([^<>])+(<\/(\D)>)/gi, "$3");
  Logger.log(textstfu);
}
```

Comment: I knew I was making a stupid mistake. When I test it though, it should read "I love pancakes I love pancakes", whereas it only returns "pancakes", which I am assuming is the non-tagged "pancakes." Why is this behavior occurring?

Comment: Your expression is greedy, so it's matching the entire string beginning to end.

Comment: Fixed: Regex should have been /(<(\D)>)([^<>]+)(<\/(\D)>)/g - The "+" inside the capturing group.

Comment: Yup, there you go. If that's the answer, then you should accept it ;)